# Problems to build info.plist property (React-native IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, yarnpkg, info.plist

I'm trying to run yarn ios to build my app.

But I have an exception:

```
ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/growerdiariesapp-fsidgwpdrbcpxubccmkpffoykvsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/growerdiariesapp.app/Info.plist /Users/flavio.luiz/Documents/learning/grower-diaries-app/growerdiariesapp/ios/growerdiariesapp/Info.plist (in target 'growerdiariesapp' from project 'growerdiariesapp')
    cd /Users/flavio.luiz/Documents/learning/grower-diaries-app/growerdiariesapp/ios
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/flavio.luiz/Documents/learning/grower-diaries-app/growerdiariesapp/ios/growerdiariesapp/Info.plist -producttype com.apple.product-type.application -genpkginfo /Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/growerdiariesapp-fsidgwpdrbcpxubccmkpffoykvsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/growerdiariesapp.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -additionalcontentfile /Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/growerdiariesapp-fsidgwpdrbcpxubccmkpffoykvsz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/growerdiariesapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/growerdiariesapp.build/LaunchScreen-SBPartialInfo.plist -additionalcontentfile /Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/growerdiariesapp-fsidgwpdrbcpxubccmkpffoykvsz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/growerdiariesapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/growerdiariesapp.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist -o /Users/flavio.luiz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/growerdiariesapp-fsidgwpdrbcpxubccmkpffoykvsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/growerdiariesapp.app/Info.plist
error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/flavio.luiz/Documents/learning/grower-diaries-app/growerdiariesapp/ios/growerdiariesapp/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'growerdiariesapp' from project 'growerdiariesapp')
```

i think that could be a problem with the properties of the info list. I recently changed the file to remove react-native-vector-icons:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>grower diaries</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I just tried `plutil info.plist` and that is the answer:

```
info.plist: Value missing for key inside <dict> at line 55
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which line is line 55? Where does it point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

I just remove UIAppFonts key from Info.plist and it worked. Key are declared but has no value reference.